# Molecular Assembly Program

Tags: atoms, computational-chemistry

I'm not totally sure which Stack Exchange community this would go in, but Chemistry seemed best.
I've been thinking for a long time now, that it would be cool to have a program where you could design your own atomic models, from the sub-atomic scale and up, then test them in a real situation. You could create anything from simple molecular structures to...anything.
I've looked around online, but there aren't any programs that you can build your own atomic structure. Anyone know if there *are* any out there like this?

EDIT: I've tried a few other programs, including Avogadro, [this](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/build-a-molecule/build-a-molecule_en.jnlp), and another one by PHET.

Comment: "*...your own atomic models...*"; do you mean "hypothetical molecules"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hypothetical'?

Comment: I mean molecules that don't exist, but since we love logo, we make them up. :)

Comment: @MARamezani I mean a program where you could, maybe with a drag & drop interface, create your own models, molecular structures, etc., then put them into a real situation and see how they act. This could maybe be used to create new medicines, simple viruses that could go in and kill a disease, or even new species. Does that help?

Comment: William, you might want to have a look at this wikipedia article on [docking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docking_%28molecular%29).

Comment: This article in [BMC Bioinformatics](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/10/168/) might be helpful too, [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fderpharmachemica.com%2Fvol6-iss6%2FDPC-2014-6-6-211-228.pdf&ei=1z3uVOX7AsXiaPK5gfAF&usg=AFQjCNGq1LrjBpCy0T3rFbQTBaZMt4ejpw&bvm=bv.86956481,d.d2s) gives some more general information on computer-assisted drug design.

Comment: "Put them into a real situation and see how they act." Oh, such thing is, I'm afraid, not out of the realm of imagination. It's really hard to make such a program: 1. "Real situations" can be aqueous, basic, acidic, etc. 2. There are oceans of molecules. If we try to know how they behave, we should write a program that has them all, literally.

Comment: @WilliamBennett As far as building small molecules, that can be done and is regularly done. Where you run into problems is modeling the "real situation". You mention drug discovery. Modeling the interactions of a small molecule in a biological system is a huge field of research. This can be helpful, but it is certainly not as simple as it appears to be. Other applications may have better models.

Comment: @WilliamBennett As far as "building your own atomic structure," there are many "molecular editors." I'm partial to mine, Avogadro (http://avogadro.cc/) but there are others. As the comments here indicate, the simulation side is more challenging.

Comment: This is a problem beyond the limits of current technology.

Answer (score 2):

You  might want to try BioVia's (formerly Accelrys) Discovery Studio Visualizer. This is free software and the "gateway drug" to their sophisticated suite of molecular modeling and chem/bio informatics software. It is a step above the various drawing programs out there and lets the user generate realistic 3-D models of an infinite variety of chemical structures. http://accelrys.com/products/discovery-studio/visualization-download.php

Answer (score 1):

> […] create your own models, molecular structures, etc., then put them into a real situation and see how they act. This could maybe be used to create new medicines […]

Imagine a huge protein that switches a malfunction (on or off) to be like a **lock**, while small organic compounds may be seen as possible **keys**.

You could either

- synthesize a huge library of potential **keys** and test them in the lab or
- build a library of **keys** on the computer and calculate their geometries, charge distribution, etc. using quantumchemical methods and then again use other programmes to examine the interaction between the **keys** and the **lock**.

The latter method, figuring out how good the keys fit, is known as **docking**.

You might want to have a look at the [CADDSuite](http://www.ball-project.org/caddsuite), developed by Oliver Kohlbacher at the University of Tübingen, but please note that these tools tend to be a tad above the entry level of simple moelcule editors.

For an online service, have a look at [SwissDock](http://www.swissdock.ch/).